# Is Mobile_Detect Overkill?

Tags: php, mobile, tablet, detect

I use [Mobile_Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) to redirect users to a mobile version if their device is either a mobile phone or tablet. I've reduced and minified the file from 72Kb down to 36Kb, but now wonder... Is Mobile_Detect overkill to detect the user's device type? Is there a way (with less overhead) to accurately detect the basic device type using php? If so, how?

```
//current code

<?php

require 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if($detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet()){header("");}

?>
```

Comment: "Mobile Detect is a _lightweight_ PHP class for detecting mobile devices"

Comment: But... Even lighter? :)

Comment: Well, the whole library uses regex for detection, it's not that slow. You call `isWhatever` based on your needs. It doesn't try to parse the UA and generate a massive data structure that you may not need. Have you tried it? Does is slow down you application?

Comment: I use it now, and it doesn't seem to slow the application. I'm just trying to eliminate every last bit of overhead that's not needed. Like just to parse "mobile" or "tablet". Maybe my efforts are overkill :)

Comment: Somebody calls it ["premature optimization"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Awesome link! I now feel "free" and revitalized, and can go to bed :D Thank you!